# Swagger UI - Expand Operations with JS

Tags: swagger-ui

I'm using swagger UI to display methods and for some reason after moving to swagger UI 2.0 my jquery click events no longer work.

Is there a programmatic way to expand all of the operations with JS? I don't want them to be expanded on page open I just need them to expand when a certain script is run.

This used to work but doesn't anymore:

```
      $('div.heading span.path a.toggleOperation').each(function (e) {
           $(this).click();         
       });
```

This also doesn't work:

```
      $('div.heading span.path a.toggleOperation').click();
```

No errors, it just seems to ignore my click events

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer and it was pretty straight forward.

When you Init swagger you will do something like this:

```
     window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            url: swaggerUrl,
            dom_id: "swaggerInjectionPoint",
            supportHeaderParams: true,
            docExpansion: 'list',
            validatorUrl: null,
            supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        });
```

At that point you have access to swaggers methods and there is one called expandAll();

so simply create an event and have that event execute:

```
    window.swaggerUi.expandAll();
```

You also have access to a few more helpful methods:

```
    collapseAll()
    listAll();
```

and a few others that can all be found in the swagger-ui.js file.

Answer (score 0):

With swagger-ui.js version 2.0.17 this javascript can be run from a browser bookmark and thus it works for pages you have no control over:

```
javascript:for (var i = 0, len = window.swaggerUi.api.apisArray.length; i < len; i++) { Docs.expandOperationsForResource(window.swaggerUi.api.apisArray[i].name) };void(0);
```